# Name for two functions that don't affect each other?

Tags: functions, terminology, convex-analysis

Is there a name for the property of two functions $f,g$ that $f(g(x)) = f(x)$ and $g(f(x)) = g(x)$ for all $x$?  For example, the closure and relative interior operations from the set of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself satisfy this relationship.

Comment: I don't know any name for it. Actually I don't know many examples either. But I am curious if someone can show an example or two.

Comment: If $f=g$ it would be called idempotent, which also gives some examples e.g. $f(x)=g(x)=|x|.$

Comment: @mathreadler: basically any two choice functions on the same equivalence relation, $x\sim y \iff f(x)=f(y) \iff g(x)=g(y)$. Examples: (1.) Distinct constant functions on a two-element set. (2.) $f(x,y)=(x,x+1)$ and $g(x,y)=(x,x^2)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ (3.) The unique functions on $\mathbb R$ with $f(x)\cong g(x)\cong x$ mod $2\pi$, but $-\pi\leq f(x)<\pi$ and $0\leq g(x)<2\pi$.

Comment: @gammatester The two conditions actually imply that $f$ and $g$ are idempotent: $f(f(x))= f(g(f(x))) = f(g(x)) = f(x)$